# Erro variavel não definida

Tags: matlab

Tenho este código e diz-me que Spec não está definido em (pcolor(freq,tstart,Spec);colorbar), mas eu estou a calcula-lo no ciclo.. Alguém percebe o porquê do erro? Obrigada!

```
N

size=N;%dimensão da Janela móvel
Nsize2=Nsize/2;
df=fNyq/Nsize2;
freq=[0:df:fNyq];
kw=0;
sw=zeros(Nsize,1);
tstart=tempo(1:Nsize:N-Nsize); %início da janela móvel
for k=1:Nsize:N-Nsize
    kw=kw+1;%Número da janela
    sw=radG(k+1:k+Nsize,NS+1);
    Fw=fft(sw);AFw=abs(Fw(1:Nsize2+1)/Nsize2);
    Spec(:,kw)=AFw
end

%fprintf(AFw)
%[nlin,ncol]=size(Spec);
figure(6);
pcolor(freq,tstart,Spec);colorbar
xlabel('f (Hz)');
ylabel('time start (s)')
figure; pcolor(periodo,tstart,Spec);colorbar
xlabel('T (s)');
ylabel('time start (s)')
```

Comment: Pode me dizer qual é a mensagem de erro que aparece no console?

Comment: O erro está acontecendo em qual linha? esta " Spec(:,kw)=AFw" ou esta "pcolor(periodo,tstart,Spec)"? pois acredito que você está tentando utilizar o Spec dentro do laço sem antes ter declarado ele.

Comment: Aparece em pcolor(periodo,tstart,Spec), e diz " undifined 'Spec' "

Comment: Cadê a variável periodo?